# Earth's magnetic and electric field in Hilly Areas

Tags: earth-observation

Can you please guide me as to what is the intensity of earth's magnetic and electric fields in different regions of earth.
Also, specifically in case of hilly or mountainious regions.

Comment: Hi Ruchi, welcome to the site. To get useful answers, you probably need to make your question more specific, and explain why you want to know.

Comment: this is a good place for information https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag/WMM/image.shtml for more detailed maps you will have to search for maps of your spesific area.as your question is now it is too broad try to limit the question to one area.

Comment: This is a different but related Earth Science SE question, and you might find comments and answers there helpful. [Is there a “submerged object” in Australia that causes a magnetic deviation of 20 degrees?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/15222/6031) This question is in The Great Outdoors SE [Can a compass be thrown off by its surroundings?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/15157/12619) Only slightly related: [How do simple compass needles remain level instead of see-sawing with magnetic dip? Are they flat even near the poles?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/21360/12619)

Comment: There are [local variations in the magnetic field](https://www.treehugger.com/natural-sciences/esa-swarm-map-earths-magnetic-field.html) but not correlated to hilliness.